# sporadically i get kernel panics Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit on my samsung

Tags: kernel, samsung

I have a samsung 7 chronos laptop with Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit. 
every so often just out of the blue it'll crash and I get a "kernel panic - not syncing; Fatal exception in interrupt"

I have noticed that there's always a message at the top stating 
"Kernel tried to execute NX-protocol page - exploit attempt?"

This happens every so often quite randomly. Any ideas what could be causing this? There's no one specific app or anything that seems to trigger this.

Please provide info! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is a protection mechanism that kicks in, see links below. Either something evil is going on or some software is broken, check the logs if it always happens when using the same program.

Also verify if the processor in your laptop is suitable for NX at all.

Relevant: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NX_bit
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_space_protection